# Responsive Table Not Working

Tags: css, responsive, css-tables

I have created a table program in which everything works fine, but when I try to make it responsive using media queries it doesn't seem to work as you can see it is uneven. Here is the CodePen for the whole code: http://codepen.io/meeksmadness/pen/YNwOoE. I have provided some images to help if you need them and any help is appreciated.

Regular Screen:

[image]

Responsive Screen:

[image]

```css
table {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  display:block;
  max-width:600px;
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  background-color:white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}

tr {
  color:black;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:400;
}

tr:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:#C5C5C5;
}

tr:first-child {
  background-color:#191919;
  color:#D3D3D3;
  font-size:23px;
  font-weight:200;
}

tr:first-child td {
  border-bottom:4px solid #696969;
}

tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom:0;
}

td {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
  padding:20px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #474747;
  border-right: 1px solid #474747;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right:0;
}

td span.special {
  display:block;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}

td>a.delete {
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
  opacity:0;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size:22px;
}

@media (max-width:600px){
  table {
    width:100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:357px){
  td span.special {
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't seem to work"?  What exactly are the results you are expecting?

Comment: @lamelemon In the responsive image it is uneven ,so I would like the table to be even when the width gets small but my code isn't working.

Comment: Your 'td' have fixed widths of 200px, you need to target these in your media query.